# get timezone from an instance of a dayjs object?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dayjs

I have a util method that takes date input and converts it to dayjs instance with timezone conversion is optional.

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';

const convertDateToLocalFormat= (date = dayjs(), isTimezoneConvesrionRequired = true)=>{
  
  dayjs.extend(utc);
  dayjs.extend(timezone);
  if(isTimezoneConvesrionRequired){
   const tZone = dayjs.tz().guess();
   return dayjs(date).tz(tZone);
  }
  return dayjs(date);

}
```

**
The problem:
**
Now if I pass an instance of daysjs object to this function, for which already timezone is applied(in the first iteration), I am getting a date which has two times timezone applied.
For example, I am Pacific time zone(browser timezone, let's say 9 am, Feb 5th, 2022). My target time zone is India (I am getting this timezone from my database). So Instead of getting 10.30 pm, Feb 5th, 2022 I am getting  12 am, Feb 6th, 2022.

**
My approach:
**
If there is a way to get timezone info from a dayjs object, I can check whether the timezone is the same. Something like this.

```
const instanceTimeZone = date.getTimeZoneInfo() // assuming date is already an instance 
                                               // of dayjs and getTimeZoneInfo() is what 
                                               // I am looking for, some util kind of 
                                               // method
if(isTimezoneConvesrionRequired && instanceTimeZone !== dayjs.tz().guess() ){
   const tZone = dayjs.tz().guess();
   return dayjs(date).tz(tZone);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
const hasTimeZone = myDayJs["$x"]["$timezone"] !== undefined;
```

The code `myDayJs["$x"]["$timezone"]` is the only way I've found that can successfully check for an existing time zone on a DayJs object. It will return the time zone name as a string if one exists, or undefined if it does not.

You could also use `myDayJs.$x.$timezone` and that will give you the same results, but it may give you UI warnings about unresolved variables.

Comment: kinda not documented feature? 
in [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimezonename) it's just a `d.zoneName`